# Dummy cordova plugin for add custom directives into AndroidManifiest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm trying to make a plugin to add certain parameters to the *AndroidManifiest.xml* 
in the official documentation is something like this, but when I try to add the plugin into INTEL XDK they show me this :

**Error:**

> Plugin Operation Error
>
> Cannot read property 'getVisibleName' of undefined

[INTEL XDK Documentation about modify androidmanifiest.xml](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/general#android-manifest)

**I appreciate if you help me , Greetings**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"     
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             id="own.plugin.onlytablet" version="1.0.0"> 

        <name>SAIT CUSTOM PLUGIN Only Tablets</name> 
        <description>Add config to AndroidManifest.xml</description> 
        <author>Own SOFTWARE</author>
        <license>MIT</license> 

        <engines> 
            <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" /> 
        </engines>  

        <!-- android --> 
        <platform name="android">

            <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest"> 
                <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                                  android:normalScreens="false"
                                  android:largeScreens="false"
                                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                                  android:anyDensity="true"
                                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
                                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
            </config-file> 
        </platform>  
    </plugin>
```

Comment: You can use this plugin to add custom parameters to the manifest by placing them on your config.xml: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

Comment: thanks @DaveAlden I solved.

Comment: But is there any solution, simpler?

Comment: same issue here, any clue?